# Capturing negative lookahead

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-negation

I need for https://github.com/mchelem/terminator-editor-plugin to capture different type of path with line number. So far I use this pattern:

`(?![ab]\/)(([^ \t\n\r\f\v:\"])+?\.(html|py|css|js|txt|xml|json|vue))(\". line |:|\n| )(([0-9]+)*)`

I'm trying to make it work for git patch format, which adds a 'a/' and 'b/' before paths, how do I make this work, I can't make the lookahead gulp the first slash. Here's the test text:

```
diff --git a/src/give/forms.py b/src/give/forms.py


 M give/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/django.po
 M agive/models/translation.py
 M give/views.py

Some problem at src/give/widgets.py:103

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/unittest/case.py", line 59, in testPartExecutor
    yield
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/unittest/case.py", line 587, in run
    self._callSetUp()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/unittest/case.py", line 546, in _callSetUp
    self.setUp()
  File "/home/projects/src/give/tests/test_models.py", line 14, in setUp
```

https://regex101.com/r/tF50pn/1

(In this link I want the same capture text except for the first line where it is currrently capturing `/src/give/forms.py` and `/src/give/forms.py` but I want `src/give/forms.py` and `src/give/forms.py`)

Comment: You can add more lookarounds after your lookahead: [`(?![ab]\/)(?<![ab](?=\/))`...](https://regex101.com/r/DY2Rfn/1) but the provided answer with use of capture groups is certainly a better choice. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have redundant groups that you can remove and make the starting `[ab]/` part optional to leave it out of first capture group.

Here is refactored and optimized regex:

```bash
(?:[ab]/)?([^ \t\n\r\f\v:"]+\.(?:html|py|css|js|txt|xml|json|vue))(?:". line |[:\n ])
```

[Updated RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tF50pn/2)

Comment: Haha the solution was so simple!